# How can a drive appear in lsblk but not in the file manager?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssd, installation, liveusb

As the only internal storage medium, I've recently installed a new and totally blank internal M.2 PCIe SSD in my Lenovo Ideapad. The [Amazon link](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B07CZ42G6F/) appears to give more information than Samsung's website, but it suffices to say that it's a Samsung PM981 512GB M.2 SSD.

As luck would have it, the BIOS recognises it just fine and, after changing from RAID mode to AHCI, it also shows up in both lsblk and sudo parted -l. However, my Xubuntu 19.10 Live USB's file manager shows no signs of knowing that it exists and neither does df -h.

It's [quite](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1127505/) [well](https://superuser.com/questions/1022849/) [known](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2408864) that Linux often has trouble recognising M.2 PCIe SSDs, but in this case lsblk is telling me that the operating system knows that the SSD is connected. How could this happen? What do I need to do so that I can safely install Xubuntu to this SSD that Xubuntu isn't fully seeing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's not in the file manager(*) or in `df` output it is likely because the file system on it hasn't been mounted, if there is one. Otherwise you can create a partition and a filesystem on it (your partition manager may help for this) and add it to /etc/fstab.

(*) and in the file manager it appears as some directory somewhere, not as a drive, so you need to know where you have mounted it

Comment: Does that imply that it should appear in Xubuntu's installer and that I should be able to use that without issue? After all, I'm sure that the installed puts a file system on the drive. Anyway, you're quite right to doubt if there's any file system. It's supposed to be a totally blank SSD.

Comment: In the installer yes, where you create partitions as a prologue to installation.

Comment: Is this answer supposed to imply that file systems are mounted? I was always under the impression that disks are. Maybe I've learned something new today.

Comment: Yes, you mount a filesystem and not a drive, even if the file system is often on a drive (but not always...). From `man mount:`: *mount -t type device dir: This tells the kernel to attach the filesystem found on device (which is of type type)  at the directory dir.*